# I get this error when I switch from light mode to dark mode

Tags: java, android

> I have created an app in which I have dark mode and light mode when I click the button for dark mode it switches from light mode to dark mode but I am getting this error not only that but when exiting this app it switches from dark mode to light off can I fix this if there is any solution for this  Please help

**This My Code**

```
binding.darkModeBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            }else{
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            }
        }
    });
```

**iam getting this Error**

```
E/ActivityInjector: get life cycle exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction
    at android.app.ActivityInjector.checkAccessControl(ActivityInjector.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:2011)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:434)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1456)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8297)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4591)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4633)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:58)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5595)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:263)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2197)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8057)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```